# No muestra el detalle de items que se envían

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy implementando MercadoPago en mi aplicación pero no me muestra el detalle de los items que estoy enviando.

Les muestro una imagen de como se ve cuando envio la info:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar **solo aparece el titulo del primer item y el total de la suma de todos los items** que estoy enviando.

Este es el **JSON** que utilicé para crear la preferencia:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Motocicleta",
      "quantity": 2,
      "currency_id": "ARS",
      "unit_price": 17776
    },
    {
      "title": "Notebook",
      "quantity": 3,
      "currency_id": "ARS",
      "unit_price": 705
    }
  ]
}
```

Y este es el que te da como ejemplo MercadoPago:

```
{ items :
        [{
            title : "Multicolor kite",
            quantity : 1,
            currency_id: "ARS",
            unit_price: 10.0
        }]
}
```

Comment: Esto no parecería una pregunta de programación, sino algo que deberías preguntarle a quien publicó esa API, ¿no te parece?

Comment: De hecho, es una pregunta para desarrolladores dirigida a quien conozca sobre esta API para eso está el tag de `mercadopago`. Saludos,

Comment: Ivan, si tu esperanza es encontrar *gente que conozca sobre esta API* este lugar, la etiqueta `mercadopago`, suele ser un **"farwest"** repleto de preguntas con votos negativos y casi ninguna respuesta. De hecho, la única respuesta a tu pregunta también de seguro te provoca más incógnitas: **¿Y porqué no muestra todos los items MP?** De seguro la solución la encontrarás una vez entres en contacto con la gente de MP.

Comment: Ahí esta mi problema Agustín, cuando haces click para ingresar a la comunidad de desarrolladores te redirecciona directamente a Stackoverflow español lo único que me da a pensar es que las preguntas las tengo que hacer acá. Este es el link de la pagina: [MP Comunnity](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/community/) si revisas mas abajo vas a ver que esta la sección donde dice: Foro de desarrolladores que te manda al siguiente link: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercadopago. Pido disculpas mi única intención es tratar de resolver mi problema sin molestar a nadie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MercadoPago por lo pronto no muestra el detalle de los items ya que este es agnóstico al proceso detrás del checkout, sino que representa un pago del total del monto acreditado, esto con el fin de simplificar compras con promociones, cuotas distintas, etc.

Como dato adicional, por defecto muestra el primer item de una lista de items en caso de recibir mas de uno.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Joel, entonces lo ideal seria modificar el JSON y enviar solo una posición con todos los datos ya procesados? Ejemplo: Compra Nro: 123213123 Total: 123$

Comment: Si, eso seria lo ideal

Comment: Muchas gracias!